# Parse asn1 files

Tags: linux, parsing, asn.1

I try to parse asn1 files. I have metadata, like this

```
HUAWEI-CG DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::=
BEGIN

CallEventRecord            ::= CHOICE 
{
              sgsnPDPRecord                      [20] SGSNPDPRecord,
--            ggsnPDPRecord                      [21] GGSNPDPRecord,
--            sgsnMMRecord                       [22] SGSNMMRecord,
--            sgsnSMORecord                      [23] SGSNSMORecord,
```

Could anybody advice to do it from linux servers (scripts or linux utility)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need an ASN.1 tool.  See http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm for an excellent list of ASN.1 Tools (some free, some commercial).

You can also try the free online ASN.1 compiler at http://asn1-playground.oss.com where you can also try encoding and decoding messages.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the ASN.1 metadata/schema, you can try to use CoDec. You can find it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/codec/

Do you have a sample binary file that I can try to parse?